# Infinite Integration in Limits of Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Given the following:
$$ u_0 = \int \limits_{ 0 } ^{ 1 } x \, dx , \:\:\: u_1 = \int \limits^{ \int \limits_{ 1/2 } ^{ 1 } x \, dx } _{ \int \limits_{ 0 } ^{ 1/2 } x \, dx } x \,dx , \:\:\: u_2 = \int \limits_{ { \int \limits_{{\int \limits _{0} ^{1/4} x \, dx}} ^{{\int \limits_{1/4} ^{2/4} x \, dx}} x \, dx}} ^{{\int \limits_{{\int \limits_{2/4} ^{3/4} x \, dx}} ^{{\int \limits_{3/4} ^{1} x \, dx}} x \, dx}} x \,dx$$

So as we can see, $ \{ u_{ i } \} _{ i = 0 } ^{ \infty } $ is in fact a sequence of real numbers, in which only three of the first few terms are shown.

So now, if $P = \displaystyle \prod _{ n = 0 } ^{ 2015 } \frac{ 1 } { 4 u_{ n } }$, how can we find $  \log_{2}P$?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which contest is this from?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

$$\log_2\left(\prod_{n=0}^{2015}\frac{1}{4u_n}\right)=3-2017\cdot2^{2016}+2015\cdot2^{2017}$$

**Necessary Identities:**

This proof will require a few formulas to work well. The first 2 all well-known but the second 2 are not as common and thus wil be proven.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=m}^na^k=a^m\frac{1-a^{n+1-m}}{1-a}\tag{1}\\
\int_b^cx^2dx=\frac{1}{2}(c^2-b^2)\tag2\\
\sum_{k=1}^nka^k=\frac{a-a^{n+1}-na^{n+1}+na^{n+2}}{(1-a)^2}\tag3\\
\end{align}$$
*Proof of* $(3)$:$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}ka^k=a+2a^2+3a^3+\ldots+(n-1)a^{n-1}+na^n\\
+a+~~a^2+~~a^3+~~~~~~~~~~~~\ldots +a^{n-1}+~~a^n\\
+a^2+~~a^3+~~~~~~~~~~~~\ldots+a^{n-1}+~~a^n\\
+a^3+~~~~~~~~~~~~\ldots+a^{n-1}+~~a^n\\
\ddots~~~~~~~~~~~~\vdots~~~~~~~~~~~~~\vdots~~\\
+a^{n-1}+~~a^n\\
+~~a^n\\
=a\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}+a^2\frac{1-a^{n-1}}{1-a}+a^3\frac{1-a^{n-2}}{1-a}\ldots+a^n\frac{1-a}{1-a}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
&=\sum_{j=1}^na^j\frac{1-a^{n+1-j}}{1-a}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{a^j-a^{n+1}}{1-a}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-a}\sum_{j=1}^na^j-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{a^{n+1}}{1-a}\\
&=\frac{a-a^{n+1}}{(1-a)^2}-\frac{na^{n+1}}{1-a}\\
&=\frac{a-a^{n+1}-na^{n+1}+na^{n+2}}{(1-a)^2}\end{align}$$

The fourth formula regards a certain sequence. The sequence is defined recursively by $a_{0,n}=n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1$ and $a_{k,n}=(a_{k-1,n})^2-(a_{k-1,n-2^{k-1}})^2$. So, for a given $n$, the first few terms are defined as

$$a_{0,n}=n^2-(n-1)^2,~~a_{1,n}=(n^2-(n-1)^2)^2-((n-1)^2-(n-2)^2)^2$$
$$a_{2,n}=((n^2-(n-1)^2)^2-((n-1)^2-(n-2)^2)^2)^2-(((n-2)^2-(n-3)^2)^2-((n-3)^2-(n-4)^2)^2)^2$$
and so on and so forth.

The needed formula is 
$$a_{k,n}=2^{3(2^k-1)-k+1}n-2^{3(2^k-1)}\tag4$$
*Proof*: Induction.

Base Case: $$a_{0,n}=2^{3(2^0-1)-0+1}n-2^{3(2^0-1)}=2n-1$$

Induction Hypothesis: Suppose $a_{j,n}=2^{3(2^j-1)-j+1}n-2^{3(2^j-1)}$ for all $n$ for all $j\leq k$.

$$a_{k+1,n}=(a_{k,n})^2-(a_{k,n-2^k})^2$$
$$=(2^{3(2^k-1)-k+1}n-2^{3(2^k-1)})^2-(2^{3(2^k-1)-k+1}(n-2^k)-2^{3(2^k-1)})^2$$
$$=(2^{3(2^k-1)-k+1}n-2^{3(2^k-1)})^2-(2^{3(2^k-1)-k+1}n-3\cdot2^{3(2^k-1)})^2$$
$$=2^{2\cdot3(2^k-1)-k+3}n-2^{2\cdot3(2^k-1)+3}$$
$$=2^{3(2^{k+1}-1)-(k+1)+1}n-2^{3(2^{k+1}-1)}$$

**The Problem**

Consider $u_k$. Using $(2)$, the integrals can be turned into a nested square that has a form very similar to that of $a_{k,2^k}$. There are, however, many extra $1/2$ terms which come 1) directly the integration and 2) from the denominators of the integration boundaries.

**Extracting the powers of $1/2$**

1) Consider the growth of the $1/2$ term as successive integrations take place (ignoring the powers of 2 in the denominators of the integration boundaries). Because of $(2)$, there is one $1/2$ term after the first round of integration (that is, the series of integrations that make $u_k$ look more like $u_{k-1}$). After each round of integration, the exponent a) multiplies by 2 (from the squaring in $(2)$) and then b)increases by 1. After $k+1$ successive integrations (so all that is left is a constant term), this factor becomes equal to $1/2^{2^{k+1}-1}$. (This is because the sequence $b_n=2^n-1$ satisfies $b_n=2b_{n-1}+1$.)

2) Before any integration, the exponent on $1/2$ contributed by the integration boundaries themselves is $k$. After each round of integration, this exponent is multiplied by 2 (from the squaring in $(2)$). Thus the total power of $1/2$ contributed by the integration boundaries is $1/2^{k2^{k+1}}$

Multiplying these together gives $$\frac{1}{2^{k2^{k+1}}\cdot2^{2^{k+1}-1}} =\frac{1}{2^{(k+1)2^{k+1}-1}}$$

$u_k$

Now that the powers of $1/2$ have been "extracted", the remaining number takes the form $a_{k,2^k}=2^{3(2^k-1)-k+1}\cdot2^k-2^{3(2^k-1)}=2^{3(2^k-1)}$. Thus the whole of $u_k$ takes the form $$\frac{2^{3(2^k-1)}}{2^{(k+1)2^{k+1}-1}}=2^{-2+(1-2k)2^k}$$

Now that we have a closed form for $u_k$, the actual problem may finally be addressed.

$$\log_2\left(\prod_{n=0}^{2015}\frac{1}{4u_n}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{2015}
(2k-1)2^k=2\sum_{k=0}^{2015}k2^k-\sum_{k=0}^{2015}2^k
$$$$=2-2^{2016}-2015\cdot2^{2016}+2015\cdot2^{2017}-2^{2016}+1=3-2017\cdot2^{2016}+2015\cdot2^{2017}$$

which is what we were looking for.